# facing this error when upgrading to atmosphere 2.4.0 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError javax/websocket/DeploymentException

Tags: jsf, primefaces, websocket, glassfish-3, atmosphere

I'm facing a problem in my jsf application when trying to upgrade from primefaces 4.0 to primface 5.3, the application was working fine using primeface 4.0 with atmosphere 2.1.7, I replaced the following jars

```
primefaces-4.0.jar
primefaces-4.0-sources.jar
atmosphere-runtime-2.1.7.jar
slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
slf4j-jdk14-1.6.1.jar
```

with the following:

```
primefaces-5.3.jar
primefaces-5.3-sources.jar
atmosphere-runtime-2.4.0.jar (as recommended by primefaces user guide)
slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar (as recommended by primefaces user guide)
slf4j-jdk14-1.7.10.jar (didn't find a jdk version 1.7.7)
```

but I faced the following error when trying to run (deploy) the application in netbeans 7.3 (Glassfish 3.1.2 websocket enabled)

```
SEVERE: PWC1420: Error invoking ServletContainerInitializer org.atmosphere.cpr.ContainerInitializer
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/websocket/DeploymentException
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.ContainerInitializer.onStartup(ContainerInitializer.java:77)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.callServletContainerInitializers(StandardContext.java:5467)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.callServletContainerInitializers(WebModule.java:581)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5363)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:733)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2019)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1669)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:301)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:212)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

it would be great if someone can help me with this issue as i'm stuck in it for a while

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Solved, By using exactly the following jars

```
primefaces-5.3.jar
primefaces-5.3-sources.jar
atmosphere-runtime-2.4.0-RC5.jar
slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar 
slf4j-jdk14-1.6.1.jar
```

and upgrading my code to use the @pushEndPoint annotation and use the EventBus instead of the deprecated PushContext, as shown in PF showcase [demo](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/push/notify.xhtml)